# Align menu to first thumbnail of responsive thumbnail grid

Tags: css, menu, grid, thumbnails

I'm trying to align a menu to a responsive column thumbnail grid. So the black menu shape is always inline with the first thumbnail. It works fine when with the smallest mobile size, but not with the other sizes is isn't inline with the first thumbnail. No one could help me so far so hope there is a code-specialist that can?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/2grghhfh/4/)

```
<header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand your complete problem. By assuming few things i tried this.

```
 `Fiddle link` http://jsfiddle.net/2grghhfh/5/.
```

By putting width as 100% for all size for nav ul ul . solves the problem.

Edit:
You will have to assign padding to nav ul for every size. Due to content padding for smallest size the col-25 content gets srinked. and for other size it is not.

Comment: It is hard to explain it properly apparently , but i don't want it 100% i want it to be 25% with 4 columns, 33.33% with 3 columns, 50% with 2 columns and 100% with 1 columns of thumbnails (last one works). Now it doesn't align with the first thumbnail on the right side.

Comment: So menu size is the same width of the first thumbnail in all responsive situations: 25%, 33.33%, 50% and 100%.

Comment: No one? help would be appreciated!

Comment: you will have to add a wrapper around nav like this and mark nav as 100% and then give margin 0 10px to nav. <div class="col-25">
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>   
 </nav>. remove all the other media css for nav

Comment: it is now tiny and not the same size of the first thumbnail width?

Comment: Menu item size same as first thumbnail size.

Comment: Yess! Only not the dropdown menu but i think i will get that working! thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to get the dropdown menu also inline with the rest. I thought to give it the same margin as 'nav' but doesn't work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2grghhfh/8/ I have done here but i think it is not a end solution i will try it again. Till then you can go with this.

Comment: I have it working now i removed the margin on 'nav' and placed it on the link